# Are SQL Server Compatibility Levels Transparent to the Client?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mcafee

I'm working with a client through the process of modernising their old server infrastructure. They have left a McAfee ePO instance for too long without upgrading and we are now dealing with an unsupported upgrade path.

As part of this modernisation the ePO's database will be moved from a local SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to a new SQL Server 2019 cluster. Unfortunately the current ePO version does not support Server 2019 and the target version does not support Server 2008 R2 so we're hitting a potential impasse.

When the database is migrated to the SQL Server 2019 cluster, it will have its compatibility level (automatically) upgraded to 2012, which **is** supported by both the source and target server versions.

My question is: from the client perspective is an SQL Server 2019 any different from an SQL Server 2012 if both servers are hosting the same database at the same compatibility level?

Will there be potential connector or API/ABI issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official stance from MS seems to be "this is fine". Specifically, they speak to it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#compatibility-levels-and-database-engine-upgrades).

From the link (for posterity):

> Database Compatibility Level is a valuable tool to assist in database
> modernization, by allowing the SQL Server Database Engine to be
> upgraded, while keeping connecting applications functional status by
> maintaining the same pre-upgrade Database Compatibility Level. This
> means that it is possible to upgrade from an older version of SQL
> Server (such as SQL Server 2008) to SQL Server 2019 (15.x) or Azure
> SQL Database (including Managed Instance) with no application changes
> (except for database connectivity).

Comment: I've seen comments to this effect around, but I'm still a bit unsure exactly what is meant by "except for database connectivity". Is that as simple as IP/credential changes, or does it potentially include swapping the connector binaries? e.g.: Could an ODBC driver for SQL Server 2012 connect to a database running on SQL Server 2019 in 2012 compatibility mode?

Comment: I interpret it as more the IP/credential side of it. If you can, upgrade your non-prod instance and try it out!